# How to control how often enemies apperar using time module in python

Tags: python, time, pygame

I am trying to make a game where you have to shoot down circles. I want the circles to appear every few seconds on the screen. I tried doing this:

```
for e in enemies:
        e.draw()
        e.move()
        if e.x <= -20:
            p.hp -= 1
            enemies.remove(e)

        then = time.time()
        now  = time.time()
        if now - then >= 4: # Calculate time difference and if it is less than 4
            for i in range(random.randint(1, 2)): # spawn more enemies
                enemies.append(Enemy())
                e.draw()
                e.move()
```

I tried putting it in my main loop but it dosent work. How can i properly calculate time difference and spawn circles every few seconds? Thanks

Comment: simply use `print()` to see what you have in `then` and `now`. If you create `then` and `now` in the same moment then they have the same value. You have to create `then` when yoiu remove emeny - it means inside `if`

Comment: BTW: maybe you should set `then` for every enemies separtelly `e.then = ...` so every enemy will use own delay to appear again.

Comment: in python it is not good to remove element from list which you iterate. Better create list with elements which you want to keep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: I would separatelly move and check collisions, separatelly check `then` add new enemy and separatelly draw enemies.

Second: I would uses list `then` to keep time for every removed enemies.

Third: In python it is not good to remove elements from list which you iterate because it can skip some elements (it will not check element which was after removed element because it moves in place of removed element). Popular method is to add to new list  elements which you want to keep and replace list after `for`-loop

```
then = [] # create at start of game

# --- only move and check collisions ---

enemies_keep = []

for item in enemies:
    item.move()
    if item.x <= -20:
        p.hp -= 1
        then.append(time.time()) 
    else:
        enemies_keep.append(item)

enemies = enemies_keep

# --- only add new enemies ---

now  = time.time()

then_keep = []

for item in then:
    if now - item >= 4: # Calculate time difference and if it is less than 4
        for i in range(random.randint(1, 2)): # spawn more enemies
           enemies.append(Enemy())
    else:
        then_keep.append(item)

then = then_keep

# --- only draw ---

for item in enemies:
    item.draw()
```